# Django ORM filter by a list and then get the last created item

Tags: django, django-queryset, django-orm

How to write the most efficient Django ORM query for the following scenario?
I need to get items based on a list of accountIds, but it will return duplicate records with the same accountId because accountId is not the primary key. Then I will need to remove the duplicates by only returning the last created record in the queryset.
I can use a for loop to loop through the list of accountIds and filter by each accountId and then order by the created date and get the latest one. However, with this approach, I will be calling the database so many times. There are more than 200 account Ids.

Are there better ways of doing this?

Comment: Can you share your model and the DB you are using? How are you generating the list of account ids too?

Comment: Sorry, cannot share this information. But I got the list of account ids from client

Comment: You can't even share the DB you are using? It's much simpler to do this if you are using PostgreSQL for example

Comment: yes it is postgresql

Answer (score 0):

This could be useful

```
Model.objects.order_by('date_created').distinct()
```

docs: [distinct in django queryset](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/querysets/#distinct)
if you are using postgres, it would be much useful and efficient

Comment: With this approach, I will still need to use a for loop to call the db for each accountId and then use the order_by() and first() to get the latest record if their accountId are the same. Is there anyway to avoid using for loop at all? I am wondering if for loop is making it inefficient?

Comment: use can use [latest](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/querysets/#latest) and this should do it

Answer (score 0):

If using PostgreSQL you can add a field name to [`distinct()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/querysets/#distinct) to create a `SELECT DISTINCT ON (foo)` query that returns the first unique value for that field. In your case if you order by `account_id` and then descending `created_date` you will get a single row per `account_id` that has the latest `created_date`

```
Item.objects.filter(
    account_id__in=account_ids
).order_by(
    'account_id', '-created_date'
).distinct('account_id')
```

Comment: Oh awesome! So can I replace distinct() here with first()? Do they return the same result? Or first() will only return one result from the entire list of Items.

Comment: @fizzbuzzzzz it's not clear what your desired result is, do you want multiple results that are the latest per account id or do you just want a single result that has the latest created date? The answer above gives the former

Comment: Okay, got it. Thanks! It's multiple results that are the latest per account id